# Flutter Web App Error: CHROME_EXECUTABLE= "..." is not executable

Tags: android-studio, google-chrome, flutter, flutter-web

I wanted to disable web security for my flutter web application.
I tried:

1. Set `export CHROME_EXECUTABLE=/path/to/google-chrome-unsafe.sh` in `$HOME/.zshrc`
2. Create `google-chrome-unsafe.sh` with the content `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="tmp-dir" $*`
3. Make it executable with `chmod a+x google-chrome-unsafe.sh`

At first this is how it worked. However, now there is always an error message. Does anyone have any idea how to solve the problem?

[Android Studio: error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsKS5.png)

Answer (score 2):

Even though you have a google chrome app in your system. It may have command like `google-chrome-stable` or `chrome` or any name to open chrome browser from terminal. Just duplicate the file with `google-chrome` name in `/usr/bin/`

Eg: I have `google-chrome-stable` as executable so my approach is like

```
cp /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

*You may have bin in snap folder or some other folder depending on your installation way*

If you're not having chrome as executable from terminal then create a symbolic link. Find you chrome binary file and use this command

```
ln -s $PATH/[google-chrome-bin] /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Replace `[google-chrome-bin]` with your binary file name

Comment: Out of all other solutions, this was the only fix that worked for me! Thanks!